# Azure Machine Learning throws error "Invalid graph: You have invalid compute target(s) in node(s)" while running the pipeline

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am facing a strange issue while dealing with Azure Machine Learning (Preview) interface.

I have designed a training pipeline, which was getting initiated on certain compute node (2 node cluster, with minimal configurations). However, it used to take lot of time for execution. So, I tried to create a new training cluster (8 node cluster, with higher config). During this process, I had created and deleted some of the training clusters.

But, strangely, since then, while submitting the pipeline I am getting error as "Invalid graph: You have invalid compute target(s) in node(s)".

Could you please advise on this situation.

Thanks,
Mitul

Comment: are you using the Pipeline Designer?

Comment: @AndersSwanson.. Yes..

Comment: any chance you could share a screenshot or the error?

Comment: @AndersSwanson.. When I tried using the same pipeline on the same compute after 2-3 days.. it has worked.. By any chance, could it be possible that "deleted clusters are not getting detached, and pipeline is trying to execute on the same old clusters"..?? Logically, it should not be.. But if it is then, it's a big bug in the system..

Answer (score 1):

I bet this was pretty frustrating. A common debugging strategy I have is to delete compute targets and create new ones. Perhaps this was another "transient" error?

Answer (score 1):

The issue should have been fixed and will be rolled out soon. Meanwhile, as a temporary solution, you can refresh the page to make it work.